# Partition array into multiple arrays, by hours

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array like this :
[Pastebin Array Exemple](http://pastebin.com/u03ZrviY)

Each array element have a key TIME. I would like to split this array by hours.

Example :

- Each array elements with key TIME between 8h - 8h59 = 1 Array
- Each array elements with key TIME between 9h - 9h59 = 1 Array
- Each array elements with key TIME between 10h - 10h59 = 1 Array
- ETC ...

And this for all hours in a day.

Could you help me with this please.

**EDITED:**

Now i have this that is working but i would like to have something much simple.

```
$sales_by_hours = array();
    foreach($sales_array as $element){

        $time = strtotime($element['TIME']);
        if ($time >= strtotime('7:00') && $time <= strtotime('7:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['7:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('8:00') && $time <= strtotime('8:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['8:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('9:00') && $time <= strtotime('9:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['9:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('10:00') && $time <= strtotime('10:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['10:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('11:00') && $time <= strtotime('11:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['11:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('12:00') && $time <= strtotime('12:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['12:00'][] = $element;
        }
        if ($time >= strtotime('13:00') && $time <= strtotime('13:59')){
            $sales_by_hours['13:00'][] = $element;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What code have you tried yourself?

Comment: Craft a minimum could case and include all the information in the question.

Comment: Anyway,  $date should be the *same* value for every value to be grouped into the bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler than what you have would be

```
$sales_by_hours = array();
foreach($sales_array as $element) {
    // the H is 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros - 00 through 23
    $key = date('H:00', $time);

    // make sure the key exists in the array
    if(!isset($sales_by_hours[$key])) {
        $sales_by_hours[$key] = array();
    }

    $sales_by_hours[$key][] = $element;
}
```